# CollectionView Item don't have same width

Tags: maui

I have a collectionview that shows one line with an image and a text and a second line with a text. All of those items should just stretch the whole width of the collection view. Unfortunately in the iOS Simulator a single item is smaller. On my actual iPhone there are multiple with a d different width.

[image]

```
<CollectionView x:Name="StatisticCollectionView"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            ItemsSource="{x:Static statistics:StatisticSelectorViewModel.StatisticItems}">

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="15,6, 12,0" >

                            <controls:Card Padding="12">

                                <controls:Card.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.GoToStatisticCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=StatisticCollectionView}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                </controls:Card.GestureRecognizers>

                                <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="6"
                                                     x:DataType="statistics:StatisticSelectorTypeViewModel">
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="6">
                                        <Image HeightRequest="15"
                                               WidthRequest="15">
                                            <Image.Source>
                                                <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialIcons"
                                                                 Glyph="{Binding IconGlyph}"
                                                                 Color="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource White}, Light={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
                                            </Image.Source>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{DynamicResource TextSubHead}" />
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource TextBodySecondary}" />
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </controls:Card>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Interestingly, if set the padding of the Grid in the DataTemplate to `Padding="15,6, 2,0"` it seems to work as expected (besides the weird low padding.
I tried to set the HorizontalOption to Fill without any change.
Also I feel that this did work until the .net update of this month, although there is no change when I set the .net Maui Version differently in the .csproj.

As a work around it seems to render as expected when I use a Margin on the card instead of a padding on the Grid.

Comment: Show the XAML of `Card`.

Comment: Card only inherits from Border and sets the Shadow. There is no XAML for it.

Comment: @ManishPradhan there was a new release that seems to have fixed that. The latest with .net 8.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting [`ItemsLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout#vertical-list) with the `GridItemsLayout`:

```
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
    <!--LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" /-->
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

And use a `Grid` in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <!-- -->
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Edit: Use ItemsLayout with GridItemsLayout and Grid in the ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to set the HorizontalOption to Fill ...

Because `Card` is a `Border`, put that on the *child* of the card, `VerticalStackLayout`.

REASON: `Border`'s job is to *wrap* its child. The child needs to ask for the size it wants.

```xml
<controls:Card ...>
    ...
    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" ...>
```